# Hidden armature meshes and physics objects are still processed for a visible armature, is there a workaround?

Tags: animation, physics, optimization

My animation playback is less than 2fps in a certain blend file. I've tried opening it with addons disabled, which brings it from <1fps to <2fps.

A have a Rigify rigged character in a scene. I have disabled everything in the scene, through both collections and the viewport visibility toggle. The only thing visible is the generated rigify armature, with no keyframes on it.

Files that playback at 25fps: Keyframed default cube, Rain, Snow, and a freshly generated Rigify rig.

UPD1: Narrowed it down to deleting the collections with physics objects in them. Any workaround to this? How can I disable physics objects correctly?

UPD2: Narrowed down further to deleting the armature modifier on two meshes, and disabling the collisions on everything. These are in disabled and hidden collections. Why are they still being processed?

UPD3: The two meshes were very dense, and had a decimate modifer before the armature on the stack, applying those along with hitting the eye button on the collisions also fixed it.

UPD4: So it seems like hidden armature modifiers and parented physics objects are all still processed on the related visible armature. That sucks, any workarounds to this?

[image: Problem file]
[image: Fresh Rigify rig]
[image: Snow]
[image: Rain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal like hiding should be, but I was able to get the fps back up to 25fps by simplifying and combining the collision meshes and applying decimation modifiers on the hidden meshes. Just reduced the total amount of vertices and objects being skinned to the rig. I'd expect adding a large set of clothing collections to have the same problem that wouldn't be able to be solved the same way though.